# Simple LDAP Login: Simple LDAP Login could not authenticate your credentials

Tags: ldap, wordpress, openldap

I have installed the `Simple LDAP Plugin` in my WordPress website at localhost. It's working fine. When I moved this website to live server. it gives the following error.

> Simple LDAP Login: Simple LDAP Login could not authenticate your
>   credentials. The security settings do not permit trying the WordPress
>   user database as a fallback.

I googled it and doesn't get any solution related to this issue.

I am understood why this issue is coming on the live server. while it's working on local machine.

Is there any permission issue or any module need to install?

Comment: Check the logs of your web server for actual errors. Most probably it's a problem of the plugin when it tries to connect to the LDAP server.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, Where can I check? Actually, I am using Linux centos machine.